# How do function inlining and Tail Call Optimization affect call stack?

Tags: programming-languages, performance, compiler, optimization, functions

I've just accidentally came across [this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/441673/427483) about inlined functions and I'd like to know how this affects call stack. But I can't add comments because I don't have enough rep so I decided to ask this question.
Also recently I discovered Tail Call Optimization (TCO) and now I want to learn more about this topic. And since TCO is also related to call stack, I actually have 2 question.

1. AFAIK **every** function call adds a new stack frame into a call stack. But what about functions inlined by a compiler? As [this IBM article](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/what-does-it-mean-inline-function-and-how-does-it-affect-program) says:

> An inline function is one for which the compiler copies the code from
> the function definition directly into the code of the calling function

It makes me think that in this case we don't really use a function at all. We use it's inner code but an actual function call doesn't happen. So does it mean that a new stack frame isn't created for such function? Hence "every function call creates a new stack frame" is a false claim?

2. TCO allows a runtime to use the same stack frame for multiple recursive function calls. New stack frames are not added into a call stack. Instead the runtime just swap data inside the same stack frame - data that was necessary for the previous recursive call is replaced with data that is necessary for the next recursive call. Does it mean that in this case we can intentionally create an infinite recursion and we won't have a stack overflow since we always have a fixed amount of stack frames in a call stack?

Those 2 question are not language specific. And since different languages have different compilers, and every language can have multiple compilers that work differently, I'd like to get answers about any language and any compiler you used and know about.

Comment: TCO is Tail Call Optimization in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> AFAIK every function call adds a new stack frame into a call stack.

This is true for some functions, but not for all functions.  On some processors, simple functions, called leaf functions (functions that may do work but simply do not call other functions), usually operate without a stack frame.  On x86, the "stack frame" (if you can even call it one) for a leaf function may be as small as one word, for holding the return address; whereas on RISC machines, may be a small as zero words.

---

Inlining is a feature of some translators, when the compiler can see the internal implementation of a called function (the callee) at the point(s) where it is translating the caller.

Inlining is usually performed at a fairly high level in the translater, such as at the AST.  The optimization substitutes the function invocation in the caller with a copy of the callee's function body.  In use, the caller behaves the same as if it had actually called the callee, as with most languages there's no mechanism *within the language* that allows us to observe whether inlining was done or not.

Inlining enables numerous other options as the callee's body is placed within the context of the caller's code — loop optimizations, common sub expressions, constant propagation, direct use of variables provided by the caller instead of formal parameters in the callee, etc..

Since with inlining there is no actual low-level function invocation, the call stack is not (necessarily) enlarged by the execution of the copy of the callee's function body.  However, the caller's call frame my be enlarged to accommodate the new code and its variables.

Inlining has limitations, and if there's recursion, inlining has to be artificially limited to some number of levels.  Since inlining makes copies of the callee's function body, the generated code may get larger (but it may also get smaller).

---

> TCO allows a runtime to use the same stack frame for multiple recursive function calls.

Tail Call Optimization applies to any function invocation that is the last operation of a function before returning to its caller.  It is very helpful in recursive code, but no recursion is required.  It applies when the last thing a function does, dynamically, is a function call, meaning that multiple return points allow for multiple TCO opportunities within the same function.

Because a tail call is specifically the last operation of an invoked function, it is the last thing it does before it returns to its caller, the caller no longer needs their own stack frame — the caller has nothing left to do (i.e. no computation or changing of state) to return to its caller — except actually return.  Thus, the TCO sets up the stack frame such that the callee returns, not to the caller, but rather directly to the caller's caller.  This removes the need for the intermediate (the caller's) stack frame, and in properly written recursive code (i.e. written for TCO) many levels of stack frames might be elided with TCO, and in addition, the caller's stack frame itself may be simpler (more like a leaf function's).

> Does it mean that in this case we can intentionally create an infinite recursion and we won't have a stack overflow since we always have a fixed amount of stack frames in a call stack?

Yes, TCO can eliminate stack overflow that might have occurred without it.

Comment: wow! Thanks for such a detailed answer! But I have a few more questions. 1) In case of recursion every recursively called function needs a stack frame of the same size. But you mentioned that recursion is not required for TCO. But there's a very small chance that a function called at the very end of a caller would need a stack frame of a size the caller needed. How does re-using the same stack frame works in this case? 2) With TCO, if (for some reason) a recursive function does not have a base case it doesn't necessarily mean that a stack overflow would occur, right?

Comment: 3) Where can I get more information about all those things you mentioned in your answer? Books, courses, youtube videos? I'm really interested in what happens under the hood when I run my program. And I want to learn more about such things. Low-level concepts are not often discussed so I discover them only when I acidentally come across them on the internet (like the post about function inlining I mentioned in my question). Maybe I should take a look at some low-level programming languages? And is the Dragon Book a good source?

Comment: The principle of TCO is that, when A calls B, and B calls C, which returns to B, which returns to A, that B erases itself and transfers to C — instead of calling C.  C then returns directly to A instead, since B has been effectively erased.  With TCO, it is possible that B didn't even need a stack frame in the first place (but it would have needed one without TCO).

Comment: In the case of recursion, B and C are the same function.  Further optimizations may be possible knowing that, for example, if B/C needs a stack frame, then it might skip setting up the frame and tearing it down, transferring control not to the beginning of B/C but just past setup of a frame, since part of that has already been done by the outer invocation.

Comment: Wikipedia is a good resource, for example, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call.  In some cases, what one needs to do is learn terminology to more effectively search for articles and videos on Wikipedia and beyond.  At the very end of that Wikipedia page, there is a box labeled "Categories:" , which allows navigation to other similar content.  For example, the first item is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Programming_language_implementation

Comment: "With TCO, it is possible that B didn't even need a stack frame in the first place" - but what about execution context of function B? Where are function arguments (for example) stored if no stack frame (SF) is created for B? I've never heard about skipping creation of a SF. I thought there were 2 technics of reducing the amount of SFs: 1) when the next function reuses the SF of the previous function 2) removing the previous SF before creating a new SF for the next function, so call stack always has the same amount of SFs, i.e. AB->AC->AD->AE where B, C, D and E are recursive functions

Comment: " if B/C needs a stack frame, then it might skip setting up the frame and tearing it down, transferring control not to the beginning of B/C but just past setup of a frame, since part of that has already been done by the outer invocation" - can't understand that :( could you please elaborate? Or share an article or a video about this mechanism so I can learn more about how this works?

Comment: Depends on the calling convention and the function, but modern processors have 16-32 registers, and their entire execution context may fit therein, including parameters.

Comment: If we know that B is calling B (the recursive case), then we know that the outer B creates a stack frame that is of exactly the right size for even the inner (recursive, next) B. So, no adjustment necessarily need be made when B calls B, and some overhead can then be bypassed.

Comment: @b3rry Assume C has been compiled like any ordinary function: Build stack frame, do your job, remove stack frame, return. The same for B. Except the very last thing B does is to call C, wait for it to return, remove B’s stack frame, return. At that point B has built its own stack frame. So instead of calling C, B jumps into C _after_ The point where C builds its stack frame. So C reuses B’s stack frame without knowing, and at the end removed Bs stack frame and returns straight to Bs caller.

Comment: Now if Bs and Cs stack frame are not identical then the compiler might know that C can happily live with a stack frame that is too large, or B might be able to make its stack frame larger quite easily. If B and C are not the same function then this saves a few nanoseconds. If they are the same function then it’s called tail recursion. In that case since B knows it’s own code some optimisations might be possible.